# Array to another array with blank values in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

Hi i am new to php actully i want to convert this array

```
Array(
[0] => 
[1] => 2
[2] => 6
[3] => 7
[4] => 
[5] => 1
[6] => 5
[7] => 6
[8] => 
[9] => 1
[10] => 3
[11] => 5)
```

I have empty valus at index 0,4,8
to another array like

```
Array([0] => 2,6,7
[1] => 1,5,6
[2] => 1,3,5)
```

Comment: [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) & [`foreach()`](http://php.net/foreach) & [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)

Comment: And what have you tried in order to do your homework? What are the problems? In any case, start off with a description of what you want done, then translate the whole thing into PHP.

Comment: Do you want the split to be on the blank items or in chunks of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st way*** if you want to group based on empty values but they are at randome indexes

```
$new_array = [];

$data = '';
foreach($array as $key=>$arr){
   if($arr == ''){
    if($key >0){
      $new_array[] = trim($data,',');
      $data = '';
    }
  }else{
     $data .= ','.$arr;
  }
}
$new_array[] = trim($data,',');
print_r($new_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/938714

***2nd way*** if you want to group based on empty values and they are at sequential indexes like 0,4,8,12...

```
$array = array_chunk($array,4);

foreach($array as &$arr){
   $arr = trim(trim(implode(',',$arr),','));
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/938698

***3rd way.*** if you want to group based on empty values and they are at sequential indexes like 0,4,8,12... (another approach)

```
$array = array_chunk(array_values(array_filter($array)),3);

foreach($array as &$arr){
   $arr = implode(',',$arr);
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/938692

***Reference:-***

[array_chunk()](http://php.net/array_chunk)

[foreach()](http://php.net/foreach)

[implode()](http://php.net/implode)

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: This obviously only works with regular groups of 3. I am not sure if that is what the OP is after. I read the question as such that the "empty" items should be seen as separators regardless of where they are positioned.

Comment: @rolfv1  added solution for that too.Please check

Answer (score 1):

Short `implode()` + `preg_split()` solution:

Extended input array is used:

```
$arr = ['', '', 2, 6, 7, '', '', 1, 5, 6, 8, 9, '', 1, 3, 5, 7, '', 10, 11, ''];
$result = preg_split('/,,+/', trim(implode(',', $arr), ','));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2,6,7
    [1] => 1,5,6,8,9
    [2] => 1,3,5,7
    [3] => 10,11
)
```

Comment: With such pattern it's easy to use `explode(',,',`

Comment: @splash58, `preg_split` is more unified in case if there would be multiple gaps like `[' ', 1, 2, ' ', ' ', ... ` You may check my update

Answer (score 0):

When meet a  `''`, just make a subarray and append the previous **non-empty** array to the result.  **[Demo](https://eval.in/938710)**.

This only cost `O(n)`

```
$result = [];
$sub = [];
foreach($array as $v){
    if($v != ''){
        $sub[] = $v;
    }else{
        if(count($sub))  // avoid continus ''
            $result[] = $sub;
        $sub = [];
    }
}
```